# Is there a quick way of undoing a folder change in Far Manager?

Tags: far-manager

I love [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com). However, it has a feature to quickly go to the root directory of a drive with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. I do sometimes need and use this feature, but more frequently I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↵</kbd> to quickly insert the file name under the cursor into the command line. As it so happens, the <kbd>↵</kbd> key is located dangerously close to <kbd>\</kbd> which is why I sometimes erroneously go the root directory (which then is doubly unfortunate since I originally wanted to work with a file in the directory I was in).

Now I could probably just redefine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to do nothing, although I still sometimes need that (can be replicated with a quick `cd\`, though). But Windows Explorer, in the wake of the WWW, provided us with a handy directory history and two separate ways of navigating backwards: backwards through the history and backwards through the hierarchy.

Is there something quick and easy to get back to the folder I were in? This is less of an issue in `C:\Users\Me` (still nagging) but more so in deeper hierarchies.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oh joy. While writing the question (and coming to the *directory history* part) I stumbled upon the solution myself. Far provides a folder history as well (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>), so doing a quick <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>↵</kbd> goes back to the previous folder.

I have now bound this to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

Comment: I made the same mistakes :)

Comment: @Joey can you please share how you bound this to a new keyboard shortcut, I am new to FAR manager and so far it has exceeded my expectations. Thanks.

Comment: @Gifcrazy: Ctrl+. or Ctrl+Shift+. to start macro recording. Same hotkey to end it. During recording there's a red `R` in the upper-left corner. See Jeremy's answer below.

Comment: @Joey, thanks, I tried, and it is working well. Only one thing, is that you cannot go back more than one directory behind. i.e. I cannot browse to my previously visited directories, something that I can do in Windows explorer using `Ctrl + <` and `Ctrl + >`. Someone should write a plugin or script in FAR for that, which is out of scope for this question. So, really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer form Joey I did it like this

Used a macro for prev folder / next folder like described in here

http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=7927

e.g. to set prev, start recording by

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

then

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

then go up to next record by

<kbd>▲</kbd>

and again

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

to finish recording.

Bind it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>◀</kbd> and you have Eclipse like prev / next navigation.